# Change the logic of application at run-time

Tags: c++, linux, runtime

I was wondering if it is possible to change the logic of an application at runtime? Meybe we could replace the implementation of an abstract class with another implementation? Or maybe we could replace a shared library at runtime...

***update:*** Suppose that I've got two implementations of function foo(x, y) and can use any of them based on `strategy pattern`. Now I want to know if it's possible to add a third implementation of foo(x, y) without restarting the application.

Comment: This sounds like a situation where you should rethink your problem rather than trying to do something wacky. What are you tring to achieve?

Comment: do you mean something like [Delegation Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) or rather [Self-Modifying Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code)? You need to specify _by whom_ the other implementation should be added!

Comment: @Meysam: Now you've added something to your question whose answers also depends on what you understand by *Strategy pattern*? Did you read about it? If you understand it, what difficulty are you facing with?

Comment: @Nawaz the `Strategy Pattern` can be used when you have implemented say two algorithms in your application and can choose any of them at runtime when needed. My need is to add a third implementation to these algorithms, later without restarting the program.

Comment: @Meysam: What do you mean by "add"? Adding code?

Comment: @Nawaz I mean Adding a new implementation of foo i.e. changing the implementation of current foo.

Comment: And I don't get the reason of down votes!

Comment: @Meysam: You're repeating the same thing again and again. What do you mean by the term "add" here? Where does the new implementation come from? It it a part of your code? Or what?

Comment: @Meysam: Just for a record, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Nawaz. I hope I can clear it this time :D suppose that based on our requirements, we decide that we only need two implementations of `foo(x, y)`. one that returns `x+y` and one that returns `x*y`. But after launching the application, I come to understand that we should have included another implementation of foo, say `(x/y)` rather than x*y in our code. The problem is that we are not able to easily replace our application with a new version to replace `x*y` with `x/y`. I want to know if it's possible to do such thing without restarting the program.

Comment: @Meysam: And I'm asking where does this `(x/y)` come from? In what form it exists? Do you want your program to pray to God, or you've written a code for that as well?  If you've written a code for that, then is it existing in some other dynamic library which is not included in your code, or is it already there in your application code and you need to call the function? or what? Do you understand what this "add a new implemention" could mean?

Comment: @Nawaz The new implementation of `foo` is not part of the application. I am looking for a `mechanism` / `design pattern`, something like a `plugin` as @Zerg said in one of the answers, that can inject the new code into the application without restarting the application. Is it possible to replace a shared library at runtime?

Comment: @Meysam: You could have mentioned that earlier, as it is clear from your question. Yes, it is definitely possible to that. That is how dynamic link library works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a plugin (a library that you will load at runtime) that expose a new foo function.
I remember we implemented something similar at school, a calculator in which we could add new operations at runtime, without having to restart the program. See [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) and [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen).

*Addenda*

Be very careful when `dlclose`-ing a plugin that it is not still used in some active call stack frame. On Linux you can call many thousands of times `dlopen` (so you could accept not `dlclose`-ing plugins, with some address space leak).

Comment: I added a comment about dlclose and number of dlopens

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, as you said *"replace the implementation of an abstract class with another implementation"* if by it you mean, you can use runtime polymorphism and change the instances of concrete classes with instances of another set of concrete classes.

More specifically, there is a well-known pattern called [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) exactly for this purpose. Have a look at the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), as it explains this very nicely, even with a code example along with diagram.

Comment: +1 For mentioning Strategy. @Meysam Take a look at this http://www.webbiscuit.co.uk/articles/the-strategy-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

C++ mechanism of virtual functions does not allow you to change the implementation at run-time.

However, you can implement whatever implementation change at runtime with function pointers.

Comment: And you could re-create appropriate instances of new classes inside a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on self-modifying code that I read recently: http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.com/2011/11/self-modifying-code-for-debug-tracing.html